# Unity: 'undo' list.RemoveAt

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making an autchess game, in the game you have a champion pool where the champions are stored and 4 champions are displayed in your shop. I want to remove champions that are visible in the shop from the champion pool, however, if you don't purchase them and refresh the shop they get sent back to the pool.

```
if(this.tag == "Clone" )//&& numberOfChampionsInPool != 0)//this where the cards in shop are loaded
{
    //print(ChampionPool.poolSize);
    DisplayChampions[0] = ChampionPool.staticPool[numberOfChampionsInPool - 1]; //the champion that is in your shop is the last element from the pool.
    ChampionPool.staticPool.RemoveAt(numberOfChampionsInPool - 1);//champion gets removed from the pool
   

    //numberOfChampionsInPool -= 1;
    ChampionPool.poolSize -= 1;
            
    championBack = false;
    this.tag = "Untagged";
    //if(refresh) { ChampionPoolChampionPool.staticPool[numberOfChampionsInPool - 1] = ??
}
```

I am going to make the refresh function separate

Comment: You need to store the shop champions pool before refreshing it, compare against the new one and the non coincident champions Add back to staticPool (no undo for RemoveAt, sorry)

Comment: How about not removing them immediately bit rather put them into another collection and only once you confirm you actually remove them?

Comment: usually programming instructions do not have an undo. You need to make it yourself and store the state you might want to return back to in case you need to restore it. For a more robust or standart implementation of an undo in an application give a look to the [command pattern](https://exceptionnotfound.net/command-pattern-in-csharp/)

Comment: And well in general the opposite would be `Insert` ... However, if you anyway always remove the last one you could simply use a `Stack`

Comment: So I made this function, but it returns argumentoutofrange:index was out of range                           public void Refresh()
    {
      
        if (numberOfChampionsInPool <= 5)
        {
            print("Refresh");
            ChampionPool.staticPool[numberOfChampionsInPool - 1]
                = ShopChampions[0];
        }
        
    }